# Do there exist positive integers $a<b-1$, such that for every $i\in\{a,a+1,a+2,\cdots,b\}$, either $\gcd(a,i)>1,\gcd(b,i)>1$

Tags: number-theory

Do there exist positive integers $a<b-1$, such that for every 
$i\in\{a,a+1,a+2,\cdots,b\}$, either $\gcd(a,i)>1,\gcd(b,i)>1$(or both)?

can you take example? I think we can consider theseform $b=a!?$(or other)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such numbers exist. Take for example $a=2184$ and $b=2200$, they satisfy the condition. This follows from the decomposition $a=2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 13\cdot 4$ and $b=2\cdot 5\cdot 11\cdot 20$. Then we have $b-a=16$, and each prime number below 16 divides either $a$ or $b$. This itself does not suffice to prove the proposed condition, but it turns out that it holds.